# Sumar totales de columnas de una tabla

Tags: php, html, jquery, datatables, codeigniter

tengo un problema y espero puedan ayudarme.

Tengo un datatable que trae ciertos datos desde un Store Procedure. La cosa es que de todos los datos que trae, al final de la tabla tengo un campo "**Total**" en el que me debería sumar todos los valores de la tabla. Y que además al momento de buscar en el filtro me sume los valores de acuerdo al filtro que ingresan.

Les dejo una foto de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logré hacer que se sumarán los valores con PHP, sumando todos los valores con un foreach pero necesito es que al momento de Buscar por filtro me sume de acuerdo al filtro los datos obtenidos.

Adjunto imagen de cuando filtro por algun campo me sigue trayendo la misma cantidad de totales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme podido explicar bien. Estoy trabajando con framework codeigniter.

Les dejo el codigo html que estoy usando:

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Detalle Informe</h3>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <a onclick="" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body table-responsive">
            <!-- <button id="test">asd</button> -->
            <table id="reportes" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"></th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette" colspan="4">ABIERTOS</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette" colspan="3">TERMINADOS</th>
                        <th colspan="2"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <th class="bg-grays-active color-palette">Área Gestión</th> -->
                        <th class="bg-grays-active color-palette">Responsable</th>
                        <th class="bg-grays-active color-palette">Área</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">Abierto en Tiempo</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">Abierto por Vencer</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">Abierto Vencido</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">Total</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">Terminado en Tiempo</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">Terminado Vencido</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">Total</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">Total Tickets</th>
                        <th class="bg-teals-active color-palette">% Cumplimiento</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $hasta = ($hasta == date("Y-m-d")) ? date("Y-m-d H:i:s") : $hasta;

                        if ($reporte) {
                            $i = 0;
                            foreach ($reporte as $u) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="bgs-grays"><?=$u->RESPONSABLE?></td>
                                <td class="bgs-grays"><?=$u->AREA_RESPONSABLE?></td>
                                <td class=" text-center">
                                    <span class="badge bg-blue abiertoEnTiempo"><?=$u->ABIERTO_EN_TIEMPO?></span>
                                </td>

                                <td class="bgs-teals text-center">
                                    <span class="badge bg-yellow"><?=$u->ABIERTO_POR_VENCER?></span>
                                </td>

                                <td class="bgs-teals text-center">
                                    <span class="badge bg-red"><?=$u->ABIERTO_VENCIDO?></span>
                                </td>

                                <td class="bgs-teals text-center">
                                    <strong><?= $u->TOTAL_ABIERTOS?></strong>
                                </td>

                                <td class="bgs-teals text-center">
                                    <span class="badge bg-green"><?=$u->TERMINADO_EN_TIEMPO?></span>
                                </td>

                                <td class="bgs-teals text-center">
                                    <span class="badge bg-red"><?=$u->TERMINADO_VENCIDO?></span>
                                </td>

                                <td class="bgs-teals text-center">
                                    <strong><?=$u->TOTAL_TERMINADOS?></strong>
                                </td>

                                <td class="bgs-teals text-center">
                                    <strong><?=$u->TOTAL_TICKET?></strong>
                                </td>

                                <td class="bgs-teals text-center">
                                    <?php if ($u->PORCENTAJE < 80) {?>
                                        <span class="badge bg-red"><?=$u->PORCENTAJE. '%'?></span>
                                    <?php } else if ($u->PORCENTAJE >= 80 && $u->PORCENTAJE <= 89) {?>
                                        <span class="badge bg-yellow"><?=$u->PORCENTAJE . '%'?></span>
                                    <?php } else {?>
                                        <span class="badge bg-green"><?=$u->PORCENTAJE . '%'?></span>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                                $totalAbiertoPendiente += $u->ABIERTO_EN_TIEMPO;
                                $totalAbiertoPorVencer += $u->ABIERTO_POR_VENCER;
                                $totalAbiertoAtrasado += $u->ABIERTO_VENCIDO;
                                $totalTotalAbiertos += $u->TOTAL_ABIERTOS;

                                $totalRespondidoEnPlazo += $u->TERMINADO_EN_TIEMPO;
                                $totalRespondidoAtrasado += $u->TERMINADO_VENCIDO;
                                $totalTotalTerminados += $u->TOTAL_TERMINADOS;

                                $totalTickets += $u->TOTAL_TICKET;
                                // $totalCumplimiento += $u->PorcentajeCumplimiento;
                                $i++;
                            ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                        ?>
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                    <td class="bg-grays-active color-palette" colspan="2"><b>Total </b></td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <strong id="abiertoEnTiempo"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <strong id="abiertoPorVencer"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <strong id="abiertoAtrasado"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <strong id="totalAbiertos"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <strong id="respondidoEnPlazo"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <strong id="respondidoAtrasado"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <strong id="totalTerminados"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <strong id="tickets"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
                        <span id="spanPorcentaje" class="badge"></span>
                    </td>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><


 $(document).ready( function () {
  jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()', function ( ) {
    return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
      if ( typeof a === 'string' ) {
        a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
      }
      if ( typeof b === 'string' ) {
        b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
      }
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
  });

        var table = $('#reportes').DataTable({
            drawCallback: function () {
            var api = this.api();
            var abiertoEnTiempo = api.column( 2, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
            var abiertoPorVencer = api.column( 3, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
            var abiertoAtrasado = api.column( 4, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
            var totalAbiertos = api.column( 5, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
            var respondidoEnPlazo = api.column( 6, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
            var respondidoAtrasado = api.column( 7, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
            var totalTerminados = api.column( 8, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
            var tickets = api.column( 9, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();

            var porcentajeCumplimiento = 0;
            //calculo del porcentaje
            if ((totalAbiertos + totalTerminados) > 0) {
                porcentajeCumplimiento = Math.round((((totalAbiertos + totalTerminados - abiertoAtrasado - respondidoAtrasado) / (totalAbiertos + totalTerminados)) * 100));
            }

            //Según el valor del porcentaje, se agrega la clase al span y se remueven las otras
            if (porcentajeCumplimiento < 80) {
                $('#spanPorcentaje').addClass('bg-red').removeClass('bg-yellow bg-green');
            } else if (porcentajeCumplimiento >= 80 && porcentajeCumplimiento <= 89) {
                $('#spanPorcentaje').addClass('bg-yellow').removeClass('bg-red bg-green');
            } else {
                $('#spanPorcentaje').addClass('bg-green').removeClass('bg-red bg-yellow');
            }

            $('#abiertoEnTiempo').html(abiertoEnTiempo);
            $('#abiertoPorVencer').html(abiertoPorVencer);
            $('#abiertoAtrasado').html(abiertoAtrasado);
            $('#totalAbiertos').html(totalAbiertos);
            $('#respondidoEnPlazo').html(respondidoEnPlazo);
            $('#respondidoAtrasado').html(respondidoAtrasado);
            $('#totalTerminados').html(totalTerminados);
            $('#tickets').html(tickets);
            $('#spanPorcentaje').html(porcentajeCumplimiento);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Por favor subes el código JS donde inicializas la tabla; la idea seria utilizar `api` de DataTables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma seria utilizar `Api` de DataTables y agregando un `id` a los elementos del DOM donde mostraras los totales:

```
<tfoot>
    <td class="bg-grays-active color-palette" colspan="2"><b>Total </b></td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <strong id="abiertoEnTiempo"></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <strong id="abiertoPorVencer"></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <strong id="abiertoAtrasado"></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <strong id="totalAbiertos"></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <strong id="respondidoEnPlazo"></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <strong id="respondidoAtrasado"></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <strong id="totalTerminados"></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <strong id="tickets"></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-teals-active color-palette text-center">
        <span id="spanPorcentaje" class="badge"></span>
    </td>
</tfoot>
```

Se registra una función de `Sum()` para `Api`, dentro del `document.ready`, antes de inicializar la tabla

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()', function ( ) {
    return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
      if ( typeof a === 'string' ) {
        a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
      }
      if ( typeof b === 'string' ) {
        b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
      }
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
});
```

Función para los valores que tienen la etiqueta **span**

> No es la mas optima pero funciona

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sumSpan()', function ( ) {
    return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
      if ( typeof a === 'string' ) {
        a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
      }
      if ( typeof b === 'string' ) {
        var regex = /(\d+)/g;
        b = b.match(regex)[0];
        b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
      }
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
});
```

Donde inicializas tu datatable debes agregar lo siguiente `drawCallback: function ()`, esta función se ejecuta cuando se cambian los datos de la tabla:

```
$('#example').DataTable(
{
  drawCallback: function () {
    var api = this.api();
    var abiertoEnTiempo = api.column( 2, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sumSpan();
    var abiertoPorVencer = api.column( 3, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sumSpan();
    var abiertoAtrasado = api.column( 4, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sumSpan();
    var totalAbiertos = api.column( 5, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
    var respondidoEnPlazo = api.column( 6, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sumSpan();
    var respondidoAtrasado = api.column( 7, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sumSpan();
    var totalTerminados = api.column( 8, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();
    var tickets = api.column( 9, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();

    var porcentajeCumplimiento = 0;
    //calculo del porcentaje
    if ((totalAbiertos + totalTerminados) > 0) {
        porcentajeCumplimiento = (((totalAbiertos + totalTerminados - abiertoAtrasado - respondidoAtrasado) / (totalAbiertos + totalTerminados)) * 100);
    }

    //Según el valor del porcentaje, se agrega la clase al span y se remueven las otras
    if (porcentajeCumplimiento < 80) {
        $('#spanPorcentaje').addClass('bg-red').removeClass('bg-yellow bg-green');
    } else if (porcentajeCumplimiento >= 80 && porcentajeCumplimiento <= 89) {
        $('#spanPorcentaje').addClass('bg-yellow').removeClass('bg-red bg-green');
    } else {
        $('#spanPorcentaje').addClass('bg-green').removeClass('bg-red bg-yellow');
    }

    $('#abiertoEnTiempo').html(abiertoEnTiempo);
    $('#abiertoPorVencer').html(abiertoPorVencer);
    $('#abiertoAtrasado').html(abiertoAtrasado);
    $('#totalAbiertos').html(totalAbiertos);
    $('#respondidoEnPlazo').html(respondidoEnPlazo);
    $('#respondidoAtrasado').html(respondidoAtrasado);
    $('#totalTerminados').html(totalTerminados);
    $('#tickets').html(tickets);
    $('#spanPorcentaje').html(porcentajeCumplimiento);
  }
});
```

En esta linea `api.column( X, {"filter":"applied"}).data().sum();` toma la columna `X` cuando se aplica el filtro; toma la data y se envía a la función `sum()` registrada anteriormente que retorna el valor de la suma.

> Agregando esta función, no necesitas realizar los acumuladores de los totales dentro del `foreach` con `PHP`, ya que cuando se carga la tabla se ejecutara automáticamente la función `drawCallback`

**Ejemplo corriendo (al filtrar el total del salary se modifica):**
http://live.datatables.net/riketele/1/edit

**Ejemplo corriendo (al filtrar el total del salary se modifica y el total de la edad [edad esta dentro de una etiqueta `span`]):**
http://live.datatables.net/riketele/3/edit

Comment: algo me funciona pero hay unos valores que vienen en negativo, sabrás por que motivo? prnt.sc/st5t63 voy a editar el post para añadir lo que hice en JS

Comment: Donde da valores negativos es donde los valores los colocas dentro de una etiqueta `span`

Comment: disculpa el abuso pero me pudieras hacer un ejm sobre eso?

Comment: para que sume correctamente tuve que quitarle le etiqueta `span` y la etiqueta `size`. Ahí me sumó los valores correctamente. Pero necesito ambas etiquetas en la tabla. Te detallo en la imagen (https://prnt.sc/st79gf)

Comment: Edite la respuesta, agregue una nueva función `sumSpan` por lo que edite también la parte de `drawCallBack` y esta un nuevo ejemplo donde se suma la edad (la edad esta dentro de un `span`)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias mi pana. Te agradezco tu dedicación hacia mi problema. Me funcionó perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tu filtro de búsqueda esta basado en html y css solamente visualizando, te recomiendo que al hacer la búsqueda la hagas también por PHP (supongo que ya tienes el array en PHP de ahí obtuviste los totales), así filtras tus registros en un array donde puedes sumar y actualizar los valores a las mismas variables que ya estas visualizando.

Entonces a tu array de objetos ejem:$Personas almacenas en un array AUX o sumas directamente el valor del registro que coincida con tu búsqueda.

Recuerda disparar el método que se encargue de filtrar tus datos junto al input text que ya esta filtrando tus registros.

Comment: el filtro es de datatables